# Get most recent row with group by and Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

Even though there are multiple questions like this I can't get my query to return the row with the most recent date with a group by.

I have the following table..

```
| message_id | from | to | created_at | status
----------------------------------------------
|    1       |   1  |  2 | 2017-04-06 |   1
|    2       |   1  |  2 | 2017-04-07 |   0
|    3       |   3  |  4 | 2017-04-06 |   1
|    4       |   3  |  4 | 2017-04-07 |   0
----------------------------------------------
```

and I'm tryin to get the rows with most recent date.

```
| message_id | from | to | created_at | status
----------------------------------------------
|    2       |   1  |  2 | 2017-04-07 |   0
|    4       |   3  |  4 | 2017-04-07 |   0
```

Currently this query returns the rows with the last recent date.

```
$messages = Message::where('to', Auth::id())
                    ->groupBy('from')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the result set will be first *grouped* then *ordered*. You can use nested select to get what you want.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY created_at DESC) t GROUP BY t.from
```

With Laravel:

```
$messages = Message::select(DB::raw('t.*'))
            ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY created_at DESC) t'))
            ->groupBy('t.from')
            ->get();
```

You just need to add your `where()` clauses.

Comment: This is the best answer after seeing all other answers in SO on similar questions.

Comment: @YubarajShrestha, are you getting any kind of errors or the result you're expecting is not correct?

Comment: Every time I use a group by it returns the oldest one, all I want is the latest. There's no error.

Comment: @YubarajShrestha can you post your query?

Comment: This solution is against the sql standard and will fail if only full group by sql mode is set, which has been the default setting for years!

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is still looking for a short and Eloquent answer for using `groupBy()` with `latest()` just add  `unique()` after `get()` like this...

```
$unreadMessages = Message::where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('read_at', null)
    ->latest()
    ->get()
    ->unique('user_id');
```

--- Update ---

Problem with the above solution is that it uses `unique()` method on the result set, which is not efficient because it operates on the entire result set after it has been retrieved from the database. This can be slow and resource-intensive, especially when dealing with large datasets.

- Solution 1

  $unreadMessages = Message::where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
  ->where('read_at', null)
  ->latest('created_at')
  ->groupBy('user_id')
  ->get();

Here, we are using `groupBy()` method instead of using `unique()` on the result set. The `groupBy()` is applied on the database level, which can be much more efficient.

- Solution 2

  $unreadMessages = Message::select('user_id', DB::raw('max(created_at) as max_created_at'), DB::raw('*'))
  ->where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
  ->where('read_at', null)
  ->groupBy('user_id')
  ->get();

In this query, we are selecting the `user_id`, `max(created_at) as max_created_at`, and `*` which will give all the columns.

By using `groupBy('user_id')` will only select the distinct user_id, and using `max(created_at) as max_created_at` it will give you the latest message per user. This way, you can retrieve the latest unread messages per user with a single query to the database.

Comment: Unique is a collection method and not a querybuilder method. This is highly inefficient.

Comment: This solution is not efficient enough. The `unique()` only works on the result set. The filtered rows on the first page will surface on the next page when paginating

Answer (score 5):

To get most recent record for each `from` you can use a self join

```
DB::table('message as m')
  ->select('m.*')
  ->leftJoin('message as m1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('m.from', '=', 'm1.from')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('m.created_at < m1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('m1.from')
  ->orderBy('m.created_at', 'DESC')
  ->paginate(10);
```

In SQL it will look like

```
select m.*
from message m
left join message m1 on m.from = m1.from
and m.created_at < m1.created_at
where m1.from is null
order by m.created_at desc
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

Comment: this is the best answer for my similar question.

Comment: Query looks great. but when I tried to add where condition above leftJoin statement. it is not giving me any result. any help?

Comment: @ManeeshRao Can you please ask a new question and elaborate your issue with relevant details, as in comments I cannot suggest without seeing the original code or condition, thanks

Comment: This is the best answer for heavy duty queries. Thanks bud

Comment: fifth line should be 
->whereRaw('m.created_at < m1.created_at');

Comment: I've tried several tips, but this one is the best.

Answer (score 4):

You may replace groupBy with distinct, as it works in my case.

```
$messages = Message::where('to', Auth::id())
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->distinct('from')
                ->paginate(10);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a date field in your example, not a datetime field, so the following is my preferred method:

```sql
# Mysql
select * from
  your_table
where date_field = (select max(date_field) from your_table)
```

```php
// Laravel
YourModel:::query()->whereRaw('date_field = (select max(date_field) from your_table)')->get();
```

- Note the above wont work as expected for datetime fields because the rows will have different timestamps, it'll likely just return the single latest row.

Answer (score -2):

You might also want to `orderBy` `message_id` as well

```
$messages = Message::where('to', Auth::id())
                    ->groupBy('from')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->orderBy('message_id', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(10);
```