# Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that contains:

```
id  seller_id   amount   created_at
1   10          100      2017-06-01 00:00:00
2   15          250      2017-06-01 00:00:00
....
154 10          10000    2017-12-24 00:00:00
255 15          25000    2017-12-24 00:00:00
```

I want to get all the latest rows for each individual seller_id. I can get the latest row for one like this:

```
$sales = Snapshot::where('seller_id', '=', 15)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->first();
```

How do I get only the latest row for each seller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get latest record for each seller_id  you can use following query

```
select s.*
from snapshot s
left join snapshot s1 on s.seller_id = s1.seller_id
and s.created_at < s1.created_at
where s1.seller_id is null
```

Using query builder you might rewrite it as

```
DB::table('snapshot as s')
  ->select('s.*')
  ->leftJoin('snapshot as s1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('s.seller_id', '=', 's1.seller_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('s.created_at < s1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('s1.seller_id')
  ->get();
```

Comment: @u_mulder thanks first i thought it using alaises as u , u1

Comment: Hi guys, I am using Laravel 5.2 and I get this error from the join: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()`. Is this a version issue do you think?

Comment: @TheRealPapa Can you try `where()` instead if `whereRaw()` i guess this functions in not available in in 5.2

Comment: Ah it was a syntax issue with the answer. Happy holidays and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
DB::table('snapshot as s')
  ->select('s.*')
  ->leftJoin('snapshot as s1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('s.seller_id', '=', 's1.seller_id');
        $join->on('s.created_at', '<', 's1.created_at');
   })
  ->whereNull('s1.seller_id')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624248/6779467, in Laravel 10, you can use `self::from` instead of `DB::table` to have the same results but with full models instead of just arrays.

*in Snapshot model (Snapshot.php)*

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

//...

public function scopeLatestForEachSeller(Builder $query): Builder
{
    /**
     * In case the table name is modified by code elsewhere,
     * we use the table name retrieval method.
     */
    $table = $this->getTable();

    return self::from($table . ' as s')
        ->select('s.*')
        ->leftJoin($table . ' as s1', function ($join) {
            $join->on('s.seller_id', '=', 's1.seller_id')
                ->on('s.created_at', '<', 's1.created_at');
        })
        ->whereNull('s1.seller_id');
}
```

*anywhere else in the code*

```
$snapshots = Snapshot::latestForEachSeller()->get();
```