# Laravel 6, MYSQL - How to Left Join a Sub Query with GroupBY using Laravel Querybuilder or Model Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

Im tried this to work it using Laravel Eloquent but i cant get exact query. So i make a raw query to get the data i want. Any one help me how to convert this into laravel eloquent or Query builder?

```
SELECT users.*,
       chat.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT a.customer_id,
          a.time,
          b.content
   FROM
     (SELECT customer_id,
             MAX(datetimestamp) TIME
      FROM chat_messages
      GROUP BY customer_id) a
   JOIN chat_messages b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   AND a.time = b.datetimestamp) chat ON users.id = chat.customer_id
WHERE users.customer_role != 0
ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to get latest chat message for each user , your query can be rewritten using left join to pick the latest record per group and it would be easier to transform such query in laravel's query builder format

### SQL

```
select u.*,c.*
from users u
join chat_messages c on u.id = c.customer_id
left join chat_messages c1 on c.customer_id = c1.customer_id and c.datetimestamp < c1.datetimestamp
where c1.customer_id is null
    and u.customer_role != 0
order by c.datetimestamp desc
```

### Query Builder

```
DB::table('users as u')
  ->select('u.*, c.*')
  ->join('chat_messages as c', 'u.id', '=', 'c.customer_id' )
  ->leftJoin('chat_messages as c1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('c.customer_id', '=', 'c1.customer_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('c.datetimestamp < c1.datetimestamp'));
   })
  ->whereNull('c1.customer_id')
  ->where('u.customer_role','!=',0)
  ->orderBy('c.datetimestamp', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

[Reference:Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

Comment: Thanks, Yes, you are right mr. @Khalid,. I`m getting the  latest chat message for each user,. It is posible using models? ,.. your answer have different results.

Comment: @AbingPj it is possible using models but you won't be able to sort users based on latest chat like using `with()` method, for results don't match can you add a sample data then we can compare results of both query versions