# Get last records from relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I have a one to many relation between Person and Visit tables like this:

```
public function visits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Visit');
}
```

And want to get the persons who has a `sickness_id` of 1 in the relation like this:

```
$persons = Person::whereHas('visits', function ($query) {
    $query->where('sickness_id',  1);
})->get();
```

And it works fine but I want to search just last visit of each person.

I mean if a person has two visits, one with `sickness_id` of 1 and other with `sickness_id` of 2, do not return this person because last visit is `sickness_id` of 2.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831563/853360 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63530199/853360

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 1):

you can use hasOne relation for that:

```
public function lastVisit()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Visit')->latest();
}
```

then you can load it:

```
$persons = Person::whereHas('lastVisit', function ($query) {
    $query->where('sickness_id',  1);
})->get();
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer is gonna work. Using [addSelect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#subquery-selects), this might also work:

```php
Person::addSelect('last_visit_id', Visit::select('id')
    ->whereColumn('person_id', 'persons.id')
    ->latest()
    ->limit(1)
)
->where('last_visit_id', 1)
->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$person = modelname::query()
     ->where(['sickness_id' => '1' ])
     ->select('visits')
     ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
     ->first();
```